# Gaussian at $q=\pm1$, log-concave polynomials, Catalan numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, combinatorial-identities

Let $[n]_q!=\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{1-q^j}{1-q}$ with $[0]_q!:=1$ and the [Gaussian polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n}k_q=\frac{[n]_q!}{[k]_q!\,\cdot\,[n-k]_q!}$. Adopt the convention that $\binom{n}k_q=0$ whenever $k<0$ or $k>n$.

One of many facts: the Gaussian polynomials are [log-concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_sequence), in the sense that the coefficients of
$$\mathcal{L}\binom{n}k_q:=\binom{n}k_q^2-\binom{n}{k-1}_q\binom{n}{k+1}_q$$
are non-negative. At present, this is the source of my motivation. First, observe that if $q=1$ then $\binom{n}k_q=\binom{n}k$ and
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\mathcal{L}\binom{n}k=C_{n+1}$$
where $C_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n$ are the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** We take $q=-1$. Are these identities valid?
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\mathcal{L}\binom{2n}k_{-1}=C_n \qquad \text{and} \qquad
> \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\mathcal{L}\binom{2n+1}k_{-1}=2C_n.$$

Comment: ${m\choose j}_{-1}$ is either a certain binomial coefficient or 0. Thus your questions reduce to binomial coefficient identities, which should be routine to prove.

Comment: This is very interesting.   I have tried to compute  $H(n,m,q)= \sum_{k=0}^{mn}\mathcal{L}\binom{mn}{k}_{q}$  if  $q=z_m$ is a primitive  m-th root of unity for some small $m,n$.
It seems that $H(n,m,z_m)=\binom{2n}{n}$ for  $m>2.$

Comment: The two identities asked by OP and another one mentioned by J. Cigler are indeed easy to prove. On my request, my graduate student Wei Xia has proved them easily.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an expanded note based on Stanley's comment in the box above.

The calculation is based on the following easily verifiable facts:

$\frac{1-q^{2j}}{1-q^{2i}}\rightarrow \frac{j}{i}, \frac{1-q^{2j}}{1-q^{2i+1}}\rightarrow 0, \frac{1-q^{2j+1}}{1-q^{2i+1}}\rightarrow 0$ as $q\rightarrow -1$. So, if one pairs up such factors (carefully) in the Gaussian polynomials then it becomes clearer that

$\binom{2n}{2k+1}_{-1}=0, \binom{2n}{2k}_{-1}=\binom{n}k, \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}_{-1}=\binom{2n+1}{2k}_{-1}=\binom{n}k$. Consequently, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\mathcal{L}\binom{2n}k_{-1}
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}j^2-\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j-1}\binom{n}{j+1} \\
&=\binom{2n}n-\binom{2n}{n-1}=C_n, \\
\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\mathcal{L}\binom{2n+1}k_{-1}
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\mathcal{L}\binom{2n+1}{2j+1}_{-1}
+\sum_{j=0}^n\mathcal{L}\binom{2n+1}{2j}_{-1} \\
&=2\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}j^2-2\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j-1}\binom{n}{j+1} \\
&=2\binom{2n}n-2\binom{2n}{n-1}=2C_n.
\end{align}

One may proceed in a similar manner to extract the claim made by Johann Cigler.